# Display loading spinner with bootstrap typeahead-loading

Tags: angularjs, spinner, loading, bootstrap-typeahead

I am building an Angular application that uses uib-typeahead and I am having trouble using the loading attribute. I would like to show a spinner while the typeahead is searching through a large dataset. Here is my code:

```
<input id="value"
   class="form-control input-sm" type="text"
   ng-model="filter"
   uib-typeahead="option.value for option in values | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:1500"
   placeholder="Select a value"
   typeahead-loading="is_Loading"
   typeahead-min-length="0"
   typeahead-editable="true">

   <span ng-if="is_Loading" id="myDiv"><img src="lib/images/ajax-spinner-large.gif" class="ajax-loader"/></span>
```

No image is showing when I am typing in the text box. Should I be assigning a $scope variable to is_Loading?

Answer (score 1):

Handle it using `ng-style`

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="filterApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   
</script>                 


<style type="text/css">
  .loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
</style>


<body ng-controller="tableController">
  <button ng-show="showLoading" ng-click="changeLoading()"> hide Loading</button>
  <button ng-show="!showLoading" ng-click="changeLoading()">show Loading</button>



  <div class="loader" ng-style={display:loaderStyle}></div>
  <script>

    var app = angular.module('filterApp',[]);

    app.controller('tableController',function($scope){
      $scope.showLoading = true;
      $scope.loaderStyle = 'block';
      

      $scope.changeLoading = function(){
        $scope.showLoading = !$scope.showLoading;
        if ($scope.showLoading) {
          $scope.loaderStyle = 'block';
        }else{
          $scope.loaderStyle = 'none';
        }

      }


    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure how to use this code with Angular UI - Bootstrap typeahead though?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep small span with image at bottom of your typeahead (or wherever you want) and add class *ng-show="loader"* then create $scope.loader and when you hit request make it true and on success make *$scope.loader = false*.